# How to convert a set of UTC dates/times into GMT/BST

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula, time

I’m trying to convert a set of dates/times that are stored in Universal Coordinated Time (UCT) format into London time, which switches between British Summer Time (BST) and Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) each year.

Let’s be crystal clear about how the UK time system works, using 2023 as an example.

On 26 March 2023 (the last Sunday) at 01:00:00 UTC (01:00:00 GMT), the clocks go forward one hour, meaning the time becomes 02:00:00 BST.

On 29 October 2023 (the last Sunday) at 01:00:00 UTC (02:00:00 BST), the clocks go back one hour, meaning the time becomes 01:00:00 GMT.

[image: UTC dates converted into GMT/BST]

The formula I’ve written in `B2` almost achieves this, except it doesn’t jump forward or back at the aforementioned times stated because it’s a second out.

```
=IF([@[Date/Time UTC]]="","",
[@[Date/Time UTC]]
+
IF(
PRODUCT(
[@[Date/Time UTC]]
-
DATE(
YEAR([@[Date/Time UTC]]),
{4,11},
1-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date/Time UTC]]),{4,11},0))
)-1/24
)
<0,
1)
/24)
```

Currently, when it’s 26 March 2023, the time has to be 01:00:01 UTC (01:00:01 GMT) for the jump forward to trigger, thus becoming 02:00:01 BST.

And when it’s 29 October 2023, the time has to be 01:00:01 UTC (02:00:01 BST) for the jump backwards to trigger, thus becoming 01:00:01 GMT.

How can I adjust the formula so it works perfectly?

Comment: Use an if() to add or subtract 1 or 2 as needed based on the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following formula to accomplish the conversion from <kbd>UTC</kbd> to <kbd>BST</kbd> using <kbd>WORKDAY.INTL( )</kbd> function, wrapped within <kbd>LET( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, [@[Date/Time UTC]],
     φ, WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(α),4,1),-1,"1111110"),
     ε, WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(α),11,1),-1,"1111110"),
     α+((α>=φ+1/24)*(α<ε+1/24))/24)
```

---

- `"1111110"` where `1` means a non working day and `0` means a working day, so it means starting from `Monday` To `Sunday` only `Sunday` is the workday in a week.

---

- `φ` -->  `WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(α),4,1),-1,"1111110")` which returns the workday (Sunday) immediately before the `1st` of `April` that is the last `Sunday` in `March`.

---

- `=φ+1/24` --> returns `1 AM` on the last `Sunday` in `March`.

---

- `ε` --> `WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(α),11,1),-1,"1111110")` similarly returns the workday (Sunday) immediately before the `1st` of `November` that is the last `Sunday` in `October`

---

- `ε+1/24` --> returns `1 AM` on the last `Sunday` in `October`.

---

## Edit: A Quick Fix To Your Existing Formula

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, [@[Date/Time UTC]],
     φ, YEAR(α),
     ε, {4,11},
     σ, DATE(φ, ε, 1 - WEEKDAY(DATE(φ, ε, 0)))+1/24,
     α + (α>=TAKE(σ,,1))*(α<DROP(σ,,1))/24)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

To convert from UTC to BST, you need to check if UTC time is during the BST interval, if it is, add and hour, if not, leave it alone.

You also need to do some rounding because of the inaccuracies in the decimal portion of floating point numbers.

This formula will work if you have the `LET` function. If you have an earlier version of Excel, you will need to expand the function.

```
=LET(
    t, MROUND([@[Date/Time UTC]], TIME(0, 0, 1)),
    m, DATE(YEAR(t), 4, 1),
    bs, m - WEEKDAY(m) + 1 + TIME(1, 0, 0),
    o, DATE(YEAR(t), 11, 1),
    be, o - WEEKDAY(o) + 1 + TIME(1, 0, 0),
    IF(AND(t >= bs, t < be), t + TIME(1, 0, 0), t)
)
```

- `t` is the UTC date/time rounded to the nearest second.
- `m` is April 1 of the UTC year
- `bd` is the start date of BST which is the preceding Sunday 1 AM relative to `m`
- `o` and `be` follow similar logic to computing the ending of BST.